# How to Set Display None To The First Td Of Second Tr

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have the below table and i want to set display none to the first td of second row.that called visi. how can i do this ?

```css
.visi{ background:orange}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="1">
<tr>
<td class="visi" rowspan="2">__</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="visi" rowspan="2">__</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easyest way is to use the css pseudo elements:

- `el:first-child`: selects the `el`-element that is the first child of it's parent. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp
- `el:nth-child(number)`: selects the n'th `el`-element of it's parent. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

join this two to get:

```
table tr:nth-child(2) > td:first-child { /* your style*/ }
```

```css
table tr:nth-child(2) > td:first-child {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="1">
<tr>
<td class="visi" rowspan="2">__</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="visi" rowspan="2">__</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`tr:nth-child(2)` selects the 2nd `tr`.
`td:nth-child(1)` selects the 1st `td`.

```css
.visi{ background:orange}

tr:nth-child(2)>td:nth-child(1) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="1">

<tr>
<td class="visi" rowspan="2">__</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="visi" rowspan="2">__</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` and `eq` method and `addClass` to hide your element.

```js
$('table').find('tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(0).addClass('hide');
```

```css
.visi {
  background: orange
}
.hide
{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellpadding="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="visi" rowspan="2">__</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="visi" rowspan="2">__</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

just replace it with this

```
<td class="visi" style="display:none;" rowspan="2">__</td>
```